# Why does 'wait' function always return -1?

Tags: c, xcode, process, fork, wait

I can't understand why the function wait always return -1 intead of the child process pid

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main (void) {
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    pid = fork ();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(2);
    }
    if ( pid == 0 ) {
        printf ("I am the child\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(pid > 0){
        printf ("I am the parent, i'll wait\n");
        pid = wait(&status);
        printf ("I waited the child: %d\n"
                , pid);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

EXPECTED "I waited the child: 1234"
ACTUAL "I waited the child: -1"

Comment: i've just tested your code and it works

Comment: not to me, and i really don't know why

Comment: how are you compiling your code?

Comment: XCode, run button. Do you think i should use gcc command?

Comment: yes, try this: gcc yourfile.c -o test

Comment: and it works... But why?

Comment: You might be missing the necessary includes for `wait`!

Comment: try to find how XCode is compiling your code

Comment: Read the compiler warnings.

Comment: It works perfectly for me (using clang), and I don't see anything wrong with it.  I can't imagine why it's not working for you under XCode.  I didn't get any warnings, either -- @klutt, what sort of warnings did you have in mind?

Comment: @SteveSummit Then it's something wrong with your compiler. I get `warning: implicit declaration of function 'wait' is invalid in C99`

Comment: @klutt Ah. Got it.  (Compiler is fine, though.  Perhaps it's something "wrong" with my copy of `<unistd.h>`, then.)

Answer (score 0):

the header file: `unistd.h` does NOT contain the prototype for `wait()`.

That prototype is exposed via the header file combination:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>`
```